# How do i draw a dotted box around the flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

Could you please help me how to draw a dotted box and name the box around the nodes in the middle column..?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please paste the source code of your figure in the text of your question. You can apply code formatting to maintain clarity

Comment: Just load the `fit` library and add `\node[draw,dashed,fit=(start)(ini)(stop)]{};`

Answer (score 4):

You've not shared a MWE.  If you provide more details about packages and libraries you're depending on, I could possible create a much better solution for you:  such as using the `fit` library or `local bounding box`.

So, just taking a snippet of what you've presented and making a few assumptions about your packages, here's one approach to creating the box you want:

[image]

The code for this:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

  \node[draw,ellipse] (start)                 {Start SIMPACK};
  \node[draw]         (ini)  [below of=start] {Set a reference system};
  \node[draw]         (pro1) [below of=ini]   {Creating/importing the bodies};

  \draw (pro1.east) -- ++ (1,0) |- (ini.east);

  \draw[dotted,red] ($(current bounding box.south east)+(6pt,-6pt)$) rectangle ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-6pt,6pt)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Then you can continue building from this after using the `current bounding box`.

Alternatively, you can use the `fit` library:

[image]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

  \node[draw,ellipse] (start)                 {Start SIMPACK};
  \node[draw]         (ini)  [below of=start] {Set a reference system};
  \node[draw]         (pro1) [below of=ini]   {Creating/importing the bodies};

  \draw (pro1.east) -- ++ (1,0) |- (ini.east);

  \node [fit=(ini) (pro1),draw,dotted,blue] {};

  \draw[dotted,red] ($(current bounding box.south east)+(6pt,-6pt)$) rectangle ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-6pt,6pt)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Code:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: open
\documentclass[tikz,border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

  \node[draw,ellipse] (start)                 {Start SIMPACK};
  \node[draw]         (ini)  [below of=start] {Set a reference system};
  \node[draw]         (pro1) [below of=ini]   {Creating/importing the bodies};

  \draw (pro1.east) -- ++ (1,0) |- (ini.east);

  \node [fit=(ini) (pro1),draw,dotted,blue] {};

  \draw[dotted,red] ($(current bounding box.south east)+(6pt,-6pt)$) rectangle ($(current bounding box.north west)+(-6pt,6pt)$);

  \node[draw] (pro2) [below of=pro1] {Outside previous bounding box calculations};

  \draw (pro2.north) -- (pro1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```